# I'm unable to debug projects using VS Code on Linux after updating to 1.30

Tags: c++, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, fedora

After updating to version 1.30 of VS Code I'm unable to debug any c++ project on Linux, even a simple "Hello World" project. However, all of my projects still work fine on Windows using the same 1.30 version.

When I try to debug, I get this error in the debug console;

```
Stopping due to fatal error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

This is happening on both my laptop and PC, both running Fedora. I quickly created an Ubuntu VM and it is also doing the same thing on a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04.

I have just tried the insider build and the problem seems to go away half the time but the times it works, I'm given some extra information in the terminal window instead of just a simple "Hello World";

```
Hello World
[1] + Done                       /usr/bin/gdb --interpreter=mi -- 
tty=${DbgTerm} 0</tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-qtiwuh3h.k9n 1>/tmp/Microsoft- 
MIEngine-Out-apeq1am0.2xp

Press any key to continue...
```

Anyone else having these problems on Linux?

If I roll back to the previous version I can get my programs to debug but I am given that extra text on the end which I had never seen before while using that version.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yes, same problem in same version 1.30.0 x64 In Ubuntu 18.04 autoupdated from snap. We should notice to VS code developers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bug has been noticed, you can watch it as [issue #2922 from cpptools](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2922).

At the moment a partial solution is given. In `launch.json` you must change `"externalConsole"` into `false`.

Comment: Correction: The value must be changed to `false`, not `true` This seems to have solved my problem for now.

Comment: I have tried but this is not helping in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu and below entry solved my problem-
In launch.json add the following on **configurations** field **"miDebuggerArgs": "-q -ex quit; wait() { fg >/dev/null; }; /bin/gdb -q --interpreter=mi",**